# How to access to common properties of a series of classes without reflection

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, design-patterns, reflection

I am working on a legacy C# application that includes many business entity classes with a 5 common properties same name same type (string and integer).

I need to implement some business process logic on the entity classes based on the 5 common properties.

```
class A
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}

}
class B
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}

}
class C
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}

}
// there more of such business classes

public static BusinessHelpr
{
   public static DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(object theRefrence)
   {
       theRefrence.CommonProperty4 = "result of some complex calculation";
       theRefrence.CommonProperty2 = 56; // result of some complex calculation;
       theRefrence.CommonProperty5 = "result of some complex calculation";
   }

}
```

If this was a greenfield application, I would inherit from a base class, that includes the 5 properties, and nicely implement the required logic

However, there is a decision that we do not do any refactoring or changing the business entities. They cannot be touched.

As such, In my helper class I need to find a way to get a reference to an object type, and access to its properties by the name of them in a string.
An obvious option here is reflection. That means I get a type, use reflection to access its properties by name in a string.
However, I learned that the use of reflection in this scenario imposes performance penalty and it is not a good practice.

Please note that I simplified the actual scenario to focus on the main point. So creating a method below won't work:

```
static DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(string CommonProperty1, int CommonProperty2, string CommonProperty3,string CommonProperty4, string CommonProperty5)
```

What are my other options, other than reflection?

Comment: You can use dynamic which is slighly faster than reflection do to caching (not my favorite though). You can check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118828/Faster-than-Reflection-Delegates-Part. The other way would be to use T4, read the assembly where the business logic is in (in compile time) and create a wrapper for each of them as partial classes ;-) <- my favorite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

I realize you said you didn't want to make any changes to the model, but one option you didn't cover is to use an interface.

```
interface ICommon
{
    string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}
}

class A : ICommon
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}
}
class B : ICommon
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}
}
class C : ICommon
{
    public string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    public int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    public string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
static DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(ICommon common)
{
    // implementation
}
```

and any of your entities will "just work".

You literally wouldn't have to make any changes to the entities *except* adding `: Interface` to each one, which is less invasive than using inheritance.

## Option 2

If you *really* don't want to make any changes to your models and don't want to incur a huge performance hit (both Reflection and `dynamic` are expensive), the only other option is to use an [adapter pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) on each of your models.

```
interface ICommon
{
    string CommonProperty1 {get;set;}
    int CommonProperty2 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty3 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty4 {get;set;}
    string CommonProperty5 {get;set;}
}
```

Create an adapter class for each of your entities.

```
class AAdapter : ICommon
{
    private readonly A inner;

    public AAdapter(A inner)
    {
        if (inner == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public string CommonProperty1 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty1; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty1 = value; }
    }
    public int CommonProperty2
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty2; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty2 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty3 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty3; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty3 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty4 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty4; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty4 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty5
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty5; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty5 = value; }
    }   
}

class BAdapter : ICommon
{
    private readonly B inner;

    public BAdapter(B inner)
    {
        if (inner == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public string CommonProperty1 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty1; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty1 = value; }
    }
    public int CommonProperty2
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty2; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty2 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty3 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty3; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty3 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty4 
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty4; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty4 = value; }
    }
    public string CommonProperty5
    {
        get { return inner.CommonProperty5; }
        set { inner.CommonProperty5 = value; }
    }   
}

// Other similar adapters...
```

Declare the method the same way as Option 1:

```
static DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(ICommon common)
{
    // implementation
}
```

And wrap your entity classes to use them.

```
DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(new AAdapter(a));
DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(new BAdapter(b));
DoSomethingOnClassAorBorC(new CAdapter(c));
```

Comment: Option 2 won't work because you didn't define T so it'll be object.

Comment: Yea, I realized that a few minutes ago. Changed back to the "normal" adapter pattern without the generic. Unfortunately, since there is no common interface, there is no way to constrain the generic to make the compiler recognize the properties.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of here is to simply wrap A, B, and C in another class that implements an interface, like ICommon:

```
    public interface ICommon
    {
        string CommonProperty1 { get; set; }
        int CommonProperty2 { get; set; }
        string CommonProperty3 { get; set; }
        string CommonProperty4 { get; set; }
        string CommonProperty5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class A2 : ICommon
    {
        private readonly A _data;

        public A2(A data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public string CommonProperty1
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty1; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty1 = value; }
        }
        public int CommonProperty2
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty2; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty2 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty3
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty3; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty3 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty4
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty4; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty4 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty5
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty5; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty5 = value; }
        }
    }

    public class B2 : ICommon
    {
        private readonly B _data;

        public B2(B data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public string CommonProperty1
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty1; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty1 = value; }
        }
        public int CommonProperty2
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty2; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty2 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty3
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty3; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty3 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty4
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty4; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty4 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty5
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty5; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty5 = value; }
        }
    }

    public class C2 : ICommon
    {
        private readonly C _data;

        public C2(C data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public string CommonProperty1
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty1; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty1 = value; }
        }
        public int CommonProperty2
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty2; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty2 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty3
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty3; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty3 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty4
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty4; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty4 = value; }
        }
        public string CommonProperty5
        {
            get { return _data.CommonProperty5; }
            set { _data.CommonProperty5 = value; }
        }
    }



        var list = new List<ICommon> { new A2(new A()), new A2(new A()), new B2(new B()), new C2(new C()) };
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.CommonProperty1 = "a";
            item.CommonProperty2 = 2;
            item.CommonProperty3 = "b";
            item.CommonProperty4 = "c";
            item.CommonProperty5 = "d";
        }
```